# What is the time complexity of recurrence 2T(n-1)+O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

What is the asymptotic complexity of T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(n)? I guess it's solved using substitution method..How to solve this recurrence? You can assume that the algorithm stops when it reaches T(1).

Comment: [O(2^n)](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-complexity-of-T-n-2T-n-1-+-C).

Answer (score 0):

The [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) can't be used here because the size shrinkage factor b (=(n-1)/n) is basically equal to 1.

However, if you calculate the first few terms, then you can easily see that the time complexity is 2**n:

```
T(1) = 1                                = 1
T(2) = 2*1 + O(n)                       = 2 + O(n)
T(3) = 2*(2*1 + O(n)) + O(n)            = 2**2 + 3O(n)
T(4) = 2*(2*(2*1 + O(n)) + O(n)) + O(n) = 2**3 + 7O(n)
    :    :    :    :    :    :    :    :    :
T(n) = 2**(n-1) + O(n) * (2**(n-1)-1)   ≈ O(2**n)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to the substitution method. If you try the straightforward approach, you'll get

```
T(n) <=? 2^n
T(n) = 2 T(n-1) + cn
     <= 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-1) + cn
     = 2^n + cn,
```

which is not less than or equal to `2^n`. The solution is not intuitive: *subtract* a low-order term. Omitting some fiddling to get the right one,

```
T(n) <=? d 2^n - cn - 2c
T(n) = 2 T(n-1) + cn
     <= 2 (d 2^(n-1) - c (n-1) - 2c) + cn
     = d 2^n - cn - 2c,
```

and set `d` to cover the base case. (Given that you want big-O, you don't even need to guess the proper term very accurately.)